# Install location for libraries from IDL projects in RedHawk 2.0

Tags: redhawksdr

The library files from building/installing an IDL project in RedHawk 1.10 installed into $OSSIEHOME/lib64 when built on a 64-bit CentOS, but with RedHawk v 2.0 they are installing into $OSSIEHOME/lib.  They are still ELF 64-bit, x86-64 but do not install into lib64.  Is this an intended change or is there a problem with the generated configure.  The old configure had logic to determine whether to append 64 to libdir but that seems to not be in the configure generated v2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change from $OSSIEHOME/lib64 to $OSSIEHOME/lib was a deliberate one. The separation between lib and lib64 under /usr is intended to separate between 32-bit and 64-bit builds that may conflict with each other. In the case of REDHAWK, there is a single install on the system, and it goes under the $OSSIEHOME directory, so there is no chance for an ambiguity. Furthermore, the differentiation between lib and lib64, because it was implemented in a macro used by all REDHAWK projects, also affected how softpkg dependencies are generated. In order to simplify the installation on the system and the layout of the directories for softpkg dependencies, the lib directories were consolidated into a single one, irrespective of architecture.

Note that if you install from RPM, the target directory on $OSSIEHOME is lib64. That is an artifact of the Red Hat RPM build package.

Comment: The manual App C says for Ubuntu that lib64 must be removed when upgrading, but there is no mention of changes for CentOS.  For CentOS there seems to be a confusion between the two with my previously installed *Interfaces.[a,la,so] in lib64 and new ones going to lib and I had to manually copy some to the other to use them.  And it was not clear whether *Interfaces.pc should be in lib/pkconfig or lib64/pkconfig